# Class Type Redefinition C++

Tags: c++, redefinition

I have seen other people asking this question before, but the answers they received were unique to their programs and unfortunately do not help me.

Firstly, I have a shape class - split into .h and .cpp files

//Shape.h

```
    #include <string>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
private:
    string mColor;

public:
    Shape(const string& color); // constructor that sets the color instance value
    string getColor() const; // a const member function that returns the obj's color val
    virtual double area() const = 0;
    virtual string toString() const = 0;
};
```

//Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

Shape::Shape(const string& color) : mColor(NULL) {
    mColor = color;
}
string Shape::getColor() const
{
    return mColor;
}
```

I keep getting an error in my Shape.h class that says 'Shape' : 'class' type redefinition. 
Any idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Does it specify the line as well? If so, what's on the line?

Comment: Does `Shape.h` have an include guard?

Comment: It specifies line 6 which happens to be the opening bracket after class Shape. And I don't have an include guard - I'm not sure what that is?

Comment: Add a #pragma once in the first line in your Shape.h. That is an include guard, as remyabel said.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I did not get any error with `g++ -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic Shape.cpp -c -o shape` and I doesn't see any mistake in the source.

Comment: Out of topic: Modify your getColor method to be: const string& getColor() const { return mColor; }    Returning a copy of the string is not optimal.

Comment: Don't use `#pragma once`. It's non-standard. Use `#ifndef SHAPE_H`...

Comment: I just added the #ifndef SHAPE_H - I think it worked. Of course, now I have new errors, but I believe you all have solved the first mystery :-)

Comment: I was using Visual Studios compiler. It seems like I needed an include guard, as remyabel mentioned above ^.^

Comment: `mColor(NULL)` will crash

Comment: @BrianBi: It's technically non-standard, but it's so widely supported that's it's not worth mentioning; for all practical purposes you're fine to use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add `include guard` to your header file

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

// put your class declaration here

#endif
```

And the way you initialize member mColor is incorrect. You can't assign NULL to string type

```
Shape::Shape(const string& color) : mColor(color) {
}
```

Add virtual destructor to Shape class as it serves as a base with virtual functions.

Also, do NOT use using directive in header file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to write an abstract base class here, but is there any other files you compiled but not showed here?

---

You must include “shape.h” twice more.
Just use macros to prevent this case.

PS：I guess Rectangle is base class of Square,and also inherited Shape.

Comment: There are, in fact. I use classes like Square, Rectangle, Circle, etc.